# ikfast plugin fails due to joint numbers mismatch

Tags: ros, ikfast, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to make an ikfast plugin for an SIA5. I follow the steps listed here (http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/ikfast/ikfast_tutorial.html) but no matter what I set as the base link and ee link and free link, I get the following errors:

```
[FATAL] Joint numbers mismatch: URDF has 7 and IKFast has 6

[ERROR] Kinematics solver of type 'sia5_sia5_kinematics/IKFastKinematicsPlugin' could not be initialized for group 'sia5'

[ERROR] Kinematics solver could not be instantiated for joint group sia5.
```

Any idea what could cause the error and how I can fix it?

I used the following command to generate the ikfast .cpp file:

```
python openrave-config --python-dir/openravepy/_openravepy_/ikfast.py --robot="$MYROBOT_NAME".dae --iktype=transform6d --baselink="$BASE_LINK" --eelink="$EEF_LINK" --freeindex="$FREE_INDEX" --savefile="$IKFAST_OUTPUT_PATH"
```

Where base link = 2,
ee link = 15,
free index = 8,

Although I did play around with different ee links and free indexes to see if that produced a different error.

Thanks!

Edit:
This is my list of links

```
name              index parents          
-----------------------------------------
base_link         0                      
sia5_connectors   1     base_link        
link_s            2     base_link        
link_l            3     link_s           
link_e            4     link_l           
link_u            5     link_e           
link_r            6     link_u           
link_b            7     link_r           
link_t            8     link_b           
tool0             9     link_t           
tool0_oriented    10    tool0            
ft_sensor         11    tool0_oriented   
plasma_pen_holder 12    ft_sensor        
plasma_pen        13    plasma_pen_holder
eef               14    plasma_pen       
wrist_connectors  15    ft_sensor
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295815/ikfast-plugin-fails-due-to-joint-numbers-mismatch/) by [cpetlowany](https://answers.ros.org/users/36157/cpetlowany/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-06-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-30**:
Which commands did you use (*exactly*) to generate the plugin? an SIA5 is a 7dof robot, so you would've to change some of the commands of the tutorial you link. Without knowing what you did, it'll be hard to help you.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-02**:
re: edit: you have `freeindex` set to `8`, which is the joint between links `b` and `t`. That is legal, but seems strange to me. For a 7dof SIA5 I would expect the `e` joint to be the free one. Do you have a specific reason for choosing the `t` joint?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-02**:
Note also: you appear to have a split in the urdf tree (two links with `base_link` as their parent). I seem to remember IKFast having a problem with that. [This section](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/ikfast/ikfast_tutorial.html#generate-ik-solver) in the tutorial you ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-02**:
.. link also mentions that. Perhaps the wrong `link` is used as the end of your chain because of that, resulting in only 6 dofs to be encoded into the plugin?

**Comment by [cpetlowany](https://answers.ros.org/users/36157/cpetlowany/) on 2018-07-02**:
No particular reason, I will try it with the `e` joint as the free joint.

**Comment by [cpetlowany](https://answers.ros.org/users/36157/cpetlowany/) on 2018-07-02**:
I will also try to remove the tree index in the urdf

**Comment by [cpetlowany](https://answers.ros.org/users/36157/cpetlowany/) on 2018-07-02**:
ikfast would not solve with the `e` joint as the free joint. I got the following error: `__main__.CannotSolveError: CannotSolveError: need 6 joints`

**Comment by [cpetlowany](https://answers.ros.org/users/36157/cpetlowany/) on 2018-07-02**:
When I try to continue using the joint between `b` and `t` but without the tree in the urdf, I still receive the same first error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm getting the impression you're running into that tree index bug. Could you try with a 'bare' urdf (so only the robot, not the rest of your cell)?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-02**:
Well, we don't know yet whether it's that bug specifically, but good to hear you got it to work. I'll post my comment as an answer.